# Mejor forma de comprobar un GET

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buenas tardes a todos !

Estoy intentando implementar una llamada GET con Jquery dónde hago la iteración de una lista y lo tengo de la siguiente forma.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.getJSON("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", function(result){
        $.each(result, function(i, field){
            console.log("UserId: " + field.userId);
            console.log("Field: " +field.id);
            console.log("Title: " + field.title);
        });
    });


    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(resp){
            console.log("OK");
            console.log(resp);
        }
    });

});

</script>
```

Pues bien me gustaría saber cuál es la forma más eficiente para iterar la lista ya que por parte de Back que es la que domino devolvería una lista vacía si no hay datos o simplemente la lista si hay información (Aún no hablo de la paginación)

Aunque por lo que he visto la respuesta de Back si la lista está vacía debería ser un 200 ya que la lista es devuelta pero vacía.

Como podría controlar la respuesta vacía desde FrontEnd  ?

Comment: `$.ajax` tiene la opción de controlar errores en caso de ocurrir... ahora lo que no entiendo es si no sabes controlar el error en ajax o enviar errores desde el back... Podrías incluir el código del back?

Comment: Bueno , he puesto un get de ejemplo , digamos que no sabría cual es la mejor forma de comprobar la lista vacía en Jquery.

Comment: en ese caso cuando vuelve de tu API, haces un if -> `$getJson(url, function(result){ if(result.length > 0) { //foreach... } }`

Comment: Que estupido he sido , vale gracias XD

Answer (score 1):

Primero intenta capturar si hay algún error en el request agregando la función de error, luego verifica si tu lista es nula o es vacía y simplemente no la muestras o en todo caso mandas algún mensaje de error.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(lista){
            console.log("OK");
            // validas si la lista es nula
            if(lista != null){
                // validas si la lista tiene elementos
                if(lista.lenght > 0){
                    $.each(lista, function(i, item){
                        console.log("item: " + item);
                    });
                }
            }
        },
        // aquí capturas cualquier error que venga del backend
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, error) { 
            console.log("status: " + textStatus); 
            console.log("error: " + error); 
        } 
    });

});

</script>
```

Ahora bien, debes tener en cuenta que a partir de la versión 3.0 de jQuery, se ha cambiado el uso de las llamadas `success`, `error`, `complete`, por `done`, `fail` y `always`. Así tendrías que cambiar tu código a esta estructura:

```
var jqxhr = $.ajax( "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts" )
  .done(function() {
    // equivalente a success
  })
  .fail(function() {
    // equivalente a error
  })
  .always(function() {
    // equivalente a complete
  });
```

---

[Documentación oficial de jQuery sobre jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)